# How to print PDF file from link opening modal box using javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, printing

I'm using VueJS and I trying to print a PDF document file that I generated by a link, example: `localhost:3000/file12.pdf`

I was reading about `window.print`, but I did get open the file in other `_blank` page, instead of modal box that I would like.

I looking for some lib, find this [PrintJS](https://printjs.crabbly.com/) but I didn't find param to open a link. Anyone can suggest me how to do it?

Comment: [try this](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/vue/documentation/pdfviewer/print/)